# AWS cli describe openshift cluster

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, openshift, redhat

Get all openshift cluster form AWS

i want to list all the openshift cluster from AWS like other 
aws eks describe-cluster --name devel  this is for eks i want it for openshift

using python is also fine 
import boto3 
eks = boto3.client('eks')

clusters = eks.list_clusters(maxResults=max_clusters, nextToken=iter_marker)

Answer (score 0):

Try to hit below command from cli.
make sure you have configured aws cli before running below command.

```
aws eks list-clusters
```

Reference url :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/list-clusters.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Mahendra, i was also thinking same eks cluster is openshift cluster,  Can you please confirm eks cluster means openshift cluster ?